# TypeScript seems to emit the wrong 'this' code (and no warning)

Tags: typescript

Their GitHub issues seem to *very much* not want me to file a feature request related to `this`, so I'll try here.

I had code like so:

```js
export class Example {
    readonly myOtherElement: HTMLElement;

    public constructor() {
        this.myOtherElement = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('myFormElement');

        document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', this.sendMessage);
    }

    private sendMessage(e: Event) {
        this.myOtherElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

With ES2015 output, this becomes:

```js
            Example = class Example {
                constructor() {
                    this.myOtherElement = document.getElementById('myFormElement');
                    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', this.sendMessage);
                }
                sendMessage(e) {
                    this.myOtherElement.style.display = 'none';
                }
            };
```

Unfortunately, this code is wrong. In the event handler, `this` doesn't actually refer to the class instance any more; instead, it becomes the context of the event (i.e., the element that sent it). So `this.myOtherElement` is actually undefined.

Now, this can be solved with a lambda:

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', e => this.sendMessage(e));
```

But the point of TypeScript is to catch more errors *before* runtime, and TypeScript IntelliSense incorrectly states that `this.myOtherElement` in the `sendMessage` function will point to an `HTMLElement`, because it infer `this` differently than JS does. Of course, if I change the TypeScript accordingly, that won't compile:

```js
    private sendMessage(e: Event) {
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

TypeScript still thinks `this` is an instance of `Example`, and accordingly errors:

> Error TS2339  (TS) Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Example'.

IMO, either of these should happen:

- with `addEventListener('submit', this.sendMessage)`, the compiler should check if `sendMessage` contains any references to `this`, and if so show a warning that the context will be incorrect.
- the emitted code should be different.

It's not clear to me if the TypeScript team agrees and it's simply a hard nut to crack?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the emitted code is just fine. The context of `this` can change depending on the caller of the function. As you pointed out, to prevent this, you can bind a function to tie it to a specific `this` context.

So what you are doing is defining a class member function. Typescript cannot know to what context `this` will change, because it is a runtime change.

`this` inside your `sendMessage` member could literally be any context. The class context, some callers context, etc.

You could have another member function that is calling `sendMessage` from the class context.

So Typescript cannot possible infer what context this will be and therefore tie it to the `Example` class context.

Comment: So why not add a compiler warning to the addEventListener function pointer that context may change at runtime?

Comment: Because this would apply to every defined function. The context of every non lambda function depends on the caller of this function. This behavior is built into Javascript, so it would not make sense to emit a warning for it.

Comment: "This function pointer points to an instance method, but may not actually pass the instance context. Did you mean to make that method a static method?"

Comment: What exactly is the point here? You are commenting a suggested message. I have nothing to do with the Typescript development, I am merely explaining why I wouldn't make any sense. If you would emit a warning message for every function, you end up with thousands of warnings, one for each fn you and all your used libraries define and call. You want to warn about a Javascript architectural decision, which is pointless.

And your message doesn't even help, because stand alone functions also have this behavior and they can't be made static. Also static methods can change context.